# display the name of user

Tags: php, facebook

this might be the simplest of questions.

```
$appapikey = '...';
$appsecret = '...';
$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);
$user_id = $facebook->require_login();
```

i have the user authenticated and everything. now i want to say hello to the user.
like:
 echo 'Hello, $user_id';

how to write that code. because what $user_id contains currently is the UID of the user.

please help.

Comment: Wouldn't it not be recommended to share encryption keys on SO?

Comment: Yes, you probably don't want to be posting those publicly. I removed them from the public-facing version.

Comment: thank you so much. totally overlooked that.

Comment: Remember to ask Facebook for a new secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add the following line to your code:

`$userInfo = $facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($user_id, array('name'));`

`$name = $userInfo[0]['name'];`

This is the same as calling the following FQL query (recommended if you are familiar with SQL as Facebook likes to change a lot of their API from time to time):

`$facebook->api_client->fql_query("SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid='$user_id'");`

Answer (score 1):

The doc wiki has PHP examples for most common calls, including the one you're looking for.

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.getInfo#Example_Requests

Comment: can i do this by using XFBML? if yes, how?